# How to get a ISO with all the Windows Server 2008 r2 updates?

Tags: windows, windows-update, iso-image, windows-server-2008-r2

Server already have Windows Server 2008 r2 installed, but instead of checking for windows updates, that takes a long time, I would like to know if there is a way to download a ISO image with all the Windows Server 2008 r2 updates, which would be downloaded using the Windows Update inside the Control Panel.

Comment: I think it would help us if you told us what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want to update a machine without network access? Do you want a copy of Windows Server 2008 to install to a new machine?

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore Sorry for few details question. Check it now please.

Comment: If you want an ISK with all the updates already installed you have to create it yourself by [stripstreaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slipstream_(computing)) them in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Windows Server 2008 R2, then you can use [WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939822(v=ws.10).aspx).

If you really need a iso use: [WSUS Offline](http://www.wsusoffline.net/docs/)

Comment: It should be noted that WSUS only downloads security updates.

Comment: @Dante do you have a reference for that? I believe you can distribute hotfixes and drivers as well

Answer (score 0):

There are no ISOs containing cumulative updates to my knowledge. That being said, you can try downloading the updates manually via [Microsoft Security Bulletin](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin).